# How to make a variable globally accessible in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I'm modifying a module in Prestashop, which has folder structure like this..

```
css
translations
index.php
module.php
module.tpl
```

There is a variable $products that has an array of all the products. But it's only accessible to module.tpl which displays all the product on the homepage which I don't like.

I created a controller that redirects to a different page and a template/view/front/products.tpl to display all the products. But that $products variable is undefined in products.tpl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created a new controller with a new template, you need to create in this controller this variable and assign this to a template, so:

In the `initContent()` function of the controller you need to create the variable "$products" with the values that you need, for example:

```
$products = Product::getProducts($id_lang, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'DESC' );
```

Then, you need to assign this php variable to a Smarty variable to show the value in the tpl file. To do this we use the method used by "@Ravinder Pal" but changing the value:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('products', $products);
```

And finally you can use this variable in the template that is assigned in the initContent() function with this:

```
{$products}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out. I had no choice but to instantiate new category and then fetch all the products.
Like this:

```
$category = new Category(Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory(), (int)Context::getContext()->language->id);
$nb = 10000;    
$products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, ($nb ? $nb : 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a constant could do the job or maybe using sessions. All is accessible by smarty in templates afterwards.

Ex in your module :

```
      define('MYGLOBALVAR', 'data');
```

In your template :

```
      $smarty.const.MYGLOBALVAR
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick reply, though it didn't really work. BTW, I was wondering if there existed a way to return multiple displays rather than just one.  Like,
hookDisplay($params) {
return $this->display(file.tpl) AND $this->display(file2.tpl);
}

Comment: You can use fetch() function. However the method above works if it's loaded before smarty.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Cookie Variable and use it where you want. like :

```
$this->context->cookie->products=$products;
```

if you want to print in tpl, in controller you can assign to smarty variable

```
 $this->context->smarty->assign('products', $this->context->cookie->products);
```

and in tpl use it